# haml and no javascript? (rails: form_remote_tag and :with parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype, haml

i am trying to call a remote method to update page content via ajax/js.
either i am too tired already or haml is not parsing the following code correctly to send the value of the query field via prototype. any ideas?

```
- form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "search", :action => "line"},:with => "'query=' + $('query').value" ) do
  %input{:type => 'text', :id => 'query'}
  %input{:type => 'submit', :value => 'Search'}
```

thanks a lot!

t

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a

```
= form_remote_tag
```

instead of

```
- form_remote_tag
```

I'm new to HAML myself but I was under the impression that you'll need the form tag to be actually generated not just executed...

Comment: `form_for` (and some other view helpers) adds the html straight into the buffer, so you don't need to insert it yourself using the `=`. If you do, you'll see two `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `:with` as part of the options hash.

```
- form_remote_tag({ :url => {:controller => "search", :action => "line"}, :with => "'query=' + $('query').value" }) do
```

If that doesn't work, debug the problem: Look at the generated html. Is the text field with id `query` the only element in the page with that id? Is the js code correct? Use the Firebug console to ensure `$('query').value` returns whatever you've entered into the text field.

Still stuck? Add your generated html into your question so we can better help.

**EDIT:** Your `query` input tag does not have a `name` attribute. Without a name, the javascript helper code skips that field when serializing the form fields...also, you do not need the `:with` code.

```
%input{:type => 'text', :id => 'query', :name => 'query'}
```

Comment: hello jonathan and thanks for your answer. the generated html seems to miss the "with" completely, see http://pastie.org/836556
(this is the output with your suggested syntax) - i think that haml might be the problem... using haml (2.2.17)

Comment: The problem is not with Haml, it's with your input tag. See my edit.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. that indeed fixed my problem (of sending the parameter without the :with) but still i am wondering how to send a :with parameter with haml.

Comment: Haml is no different from erb when it comes to ruby code. Just pass the params as usual.

In the case of `form_remote_tag`, have a look at the docs - it doesn't take `:with` as part of the options.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. also thanks for your fast answers. much oblidged.